# Autologin on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, login

I have a machine running Ubuntu Server.  It has only a command-line interface.  How can I make the system login with a specific user automatically (I don't want to type the username/password).  I know that this is insecure and I don't care.

Comment: Are you talking about logging in from the console or a remote system?  If you are connecting from a remote system just setup SSH key-based authentication.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer.  I mean from the console of the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [`mingetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/en/man8/mingetty.8.html).

```
sudo apt-get install mingetty
```

Edit your `/etc/event.d/tty1` and change this line:

```
exec /sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

to:

```
exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin username tty1
```

Comment: I did not have a file called `/etc/event.d/tty1`.  I created one and followed the rest of the instructions, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @hekevintran: What version of Ubuntu? Do you have a `/etc/init/tty1.conf`? If so, make the change there.

Comment: I'm running 10.04.